# API calls are unresponsive

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

I tried to use some of the services provided by the Google cloud API, followed the tutorial, and after installing the SDK and authorization files, I started calling. But either way, the program gets stuck after it executes, and then it waits, with no results or any errors. Trying to use Java and python is the same thing. How do you troubleshoot this problem now

I use it in China, but I already use the global proxy model. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to download some of the python packages

```
import six
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types

text = 'President Kennedy spoke at the White House.'

client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
    text = text.decode('utf-8')

# Instantiates a plain text document.
document = types.Document(
    content=text,
    type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

# Detects syntax in the document. You can also analyze HTML with:
#   document.type == enums.Document.Type.HTML
tokens = client.analyze_syntax(document).tokens

for token in tokens:
    part_of_speech_tag = enums.PartOfSpeech.Tag(token.part_of_speech.tag)
    print(u'{}: {}'.format(part_of_speech_tag.name,
                           token.text.content))
```

No useful information or error messages could be obtained, and the program did not interrupt, waiting for the result to be returned

Answer (score 0):

China blocks many/most Google services (endpoints) from being accessed inside China. If you are doing this at home, this is almost a certainty.

Your best option is to signup with Alibaba Cloud and then use a VM to access Google services. Alibaba's network will "usually" get you thru the great firewall.